# Merging given objects

Tags: javascript

I am just learning javascript and I need to know how I will go about doing this please:

Task: Merge the given objects into var C

```
var a = {
    name: "Danny"
};

var b = {
    getName: function () {
         return this.name;
    }
};
```

Output should be danny

```
var solve = function () {
    var C;

    var instance = new C();

    console.log("Name: "+ instance.getName());
};
solve();
```

Comment: What have you tried, and what problems have you run into? People are significantly more inclined to help if they see evidence of effort as opposed to a code dump =)

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`Object.assign()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) to merge existing objects into any other object.  The syntax is:

```
Object.assign(target, src1, src2, ....);
```

And, here it is working with your code:

```js
var a = {
    name: "Danny"
};

    
var b = {
    getName: function () {
         return this.name;
    }
};

var C = function() {
    Object.assign(this, a, b);
}
var instance = new C();
console.log("Name: "+ instance.getName());
```